# three div with one right side with full height and rest up and down in flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Does is possible to make three div with one right side and rest up and down in `flexbox` **without changing divs**? Expecting result like

Desktop view:

[image]

Mobile view:

[image]

Current work  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jwweqr

```css
.my-wrap {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 50px auto;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  color: #fff;
}
.my-wrap p {
  margin: 10px;
}

.wrap-one, .wrap-two {
  width: 75%;
}

.wrap-one {
  background-color: tomato;
}

.wrap-two {
  background-color: deepskyblue;
}

.wrap-three {
  background-color: greenyellow;
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 25%;
      flex-basis: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-wrap">
  <div class="wrap-one">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum voluptates ipsa tempora qui voluptas, dicta corrupti dolorum, iure esse earum ut pariatur, ad possimus facilis consequatur impedit accusantium autem! Nesciunt?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap-two">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat commodi aspernatur et! Voluptates officiis nemo corporis delectus pariatur. Cupiditate perspiciatis illum minima, porro voluptas velit nobis ad eveniet modi explicabo.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap-three">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis reprehenderit, necessitatibus vel praesentium dolorum vitae sequi in magni voluptate alias fugit saepe eos sint dolore quae sapiente sunt itaque, cupiditate.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: My first thought is to nest flex containers. Outer `.my-wrap` is a flex container with 2 sections inside, one for the two stacked bars, the second for the far right bar. Then make the wrapper around the stacked bars a flex container as well and give them a 100% flex-basis or min-width and set them to wrap. I'm working it out now and will follow up.

Comment: making another div is may not work because it will break responsive design

Comment: How would you like it to look on smaller screens? 3 vertically-stacked bars?

Comment: @bobbyz Please have a look updated view